# location of ionic, cordova and npm packages

Tags: ionic-framework, npm, ionic2, ionic3

I'm not sure if ionic framework and cordova package dependencies be local vs global.

I installed ionic and cordova as global but at the same time when I ran npm install on an ionic project it installed a local package.

Now running ionic info on different projects give me different versions.
Should I remove the ionic and cordova from the local package.json? As ionic recommends it to be kept global.

Then how would developers who share a project deal with different versions of ionic in their respective machines?

Answer (score 1):

Ionic and Cordova should be installed as global packages. This will provide you the necessary CLI commands for example to create new projects using `ionic start xyz` etc.

When creating a new project Ionic will automatically add all the required dependencies like `@ionic/angular` to your projects and save the version information in your `package-lock.json` file. When other developers work on your project they simply need to use `npm install` to get the same versions.

Cordova version is a different story and has been a source of constant pain for Ionic developers. Mostly because the packages `cordova-ios` and `cordova-android` may not support certain Cordova versions. We're currently using Cordova 8.1.2 throughout the team and it has been stable so far.